# Stock portfolio database design to support stock split/merge

Tags: mysql, database, stock, portfolio

I am currently creating a web application to manage my stock portfolio, but when it comes to the transaction table, I have some problem I want to ask.

The following is my stock transaction table design:

```
|   column name  |       datatype       |
|----------------|----------------------|
|       id       |        int(10)       | primary key, auto increment
|  portfolio_id  |        int(10)       | reference to portfolio table primary key
|      symbol    |      varchar(20)     | stock symbol e.g: YHOO, GOOG
|       type     |  ENUM('buy','sell')  |
|     tx_date    |         DATE         |
|      price     |     DOUBLE(15,2)     |
|     volume     |        int(20)       |
|    commission  |     DOUBLE(15,2)     |
|    created_at  |       TIMESTAMP      |
|    updated_at  |       TIMESTAMP      |
```

In my current design, I don't have an extra table for storing the stock symbol. I generate a list of stock symbols (using some stock api) for the user to pick when they try to create a new transaction record, and I think that this approach may cause some problem when there is stock split/merge, because I may not be able to retrieve the stock price again using the same symbol.

I would like to know how I should modify my table, in order to support the stock split/merge case?

Answer (score 1):

**Stock splits**

```
... symbol type   shares ...
... AAPL   split  100    ...
```

2 for 1 split; 100 shares became 200 shares.

**Dividends**

```
symbol  type  amount
AAPL    div   20.00
```

**Mergers**

Workaround: Record a merger as a sale or the old stock and a buy of the new stock. Add appropriate notes in the 'notes' column.

A more accurate (but more complicated) strategy is to redesign the entire database so that each trade is literally a trade of one transaction for another. A 'buy' trades cash for stock. A 'sell' trades stock for cash. A merger trades stock A for stock B. A split trades 0 shares for 100 shares, etc. Cash is just another asset class.

**Foreign stocks**

All the major finance sites have this figured out. symbol.exchange is a unique id. No need to reinvent the wheel and create a new id column.

You will also need to add a currency column for foreign stocks.

Answer (score 0):

There are less than 4000 stocks in USA. Why don't you use the stock symbol as the Primary Key. How do you plan for dividends?

Comment: Because I would like to support also those stocks outside USA.
And even I set the symbol as the primary key, the problem about stock split/merge cannot be fixed.

For the dividends part, I guess I will add it to the portfolio's realized Profit. But not stored in the transaction table

Answer (score 0):

I like your approach of having your own custom security (stock) ID. You can then map this to various ticker/CUSIP/ISIN changes over time from the exchange/data provider. So have a security_master table which has your security_ID, and a separate <data_provider>_security table with the one-to-many mappings. And a third security events table (splits, mergers, etc)

Your transaction, holding, and any other tables which refer to securities, will only refer to your internal security ID.

If a stock splits, you still refer to it using the same security_id, but it would map to a security events table that tracks over time, and you would query the appropriate quantity based on the split ratio for that point in time.